# How to generate and copy a SSH key in one line on macOS?

Tags: shell, ssh, command-line, copy

I use this command to generate a key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`
```

However I do not want to save it as a file, instead I would like to copy it to my clipboard so it is ready to be pasted.

How can I do that? How to combine this with some sort of *copy to clipboard* command?

I tried the following command but it didn't work:

```
pbcopy ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Comment: `| tee xclip` maybe?

Comment: @BenjaminW. added that at the end, did not work...

Comment: Oh, it doesn't actually print to stdout...

Answer (score 2):

You should create a script (or a function) to achieve this. Example with a script:

**genkey.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com" -f $1 && pbcopy < $1.pub
```

The first command generates a key at the location given in the first argument of the script. The second one, `pbcopy`, copies the content of the newly-generated public key in your clipboard.

When running the script, feed it the path to the private key you want to generate:

```
sh genkey.sh ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```